# BeautifulSoup and lxml in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml, jupyter

I'm having trouble with BeautifulSoup and lxml running inside a Docker container that serves jupyter notebooks.

I've installed lxml via `sudo pip install lxml`, and if I run an interactive python interpreter, all works fine:

```
    >>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
    >>> bs('test','lxml')
    <html><body><p>test</p></body></html>
```

If I run the same code inside a Jupyter notebook, it gives me the following error

```
    FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml.
```

`sys.executable` returns `/opt/ds/bin/python3` in both cases.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The interpreter is opened with `python` or `python3`. It seems that Jupyter runs python3. Are you ran `sudo pip3 install lxml`?

Comment: Everything is run with python3, also pip indeed.

Comment: Does direct import works?

```import bs4.builder._lxml```
and 
```from lxml import etree``` ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Saved, closed and opened the program again and its working fine now, no extra import statements needed. My guess is the Restart and Run All would also do the same.. basically kernel (I'm running a jupyter notebook) had to be restarted to be able to use the lxml I'd just installed using pip.